# Return from Camera when called with startActivityForResult()

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using the camera by creating an intent:

```
Intent cameraI = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

and then starting it with:

```
startActivityForResult(cameraI, request);
```

where request is a predefined constant integer.

I then have the onActivityResult():

```
public void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent data) throws NullPointerException
{
    try{

    super.onActivityResult(req, res, data);
    if(req == request)
    {
        Bitmap picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image.setImageBitmap(picture);
    }//if
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No picture taken", 4);
    }//else
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        String error = "null pointer exception";
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error, 4);
    }
}//onActivityResult
```

My predicament is that I do not have a camera on this computer. I get eclipse's default checkerboard and moving square animation. Does this actually function? I have been clicking the "take picture" button but nothing is happening. What I want to happen is to take a single picture, and then return it to the activity that called i. Is that the default action or do I have to specify that I want it to return after taking one picture?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: That is the sort of thing you really should be testing on a device.

Comment: Yes that is the default action. As soon as the user clicks a picture, the camera activity will return with the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in question ended up working. Upon testing on a device, the picture was returned as desired. Eclipse's emulated camera simply did not work. If i recall correctly you can enable a camera, but that is a different discussion entirely.

Answer (score 2):

YEah, the newer emulators(2.3.3) should be fine for testing.

Some devices have the problems of returning data in different formats. Instead, what you could do is, pass a location(you can choose) to the camera app, and it would save the new image to that location, and you can just blindly use the location that you have specified.

For example

```
File tempFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                + "/myfolder");
        tempFolder.mkdir();
        file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/myfolder",
                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

Comment: So if i do this the image will not be saved to the default gallery? That would actually be really helpful.

Comment: Yes. But it will show up in the gallery app but in a different folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the simulator and what it is capable of, but here is a tutorial that you might find helpful:

http://achorniy.wordpress.com/2010/04/26/howto-launch-android-camera-using-intents/