# Capturing an image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

In my application, I want to capture an image with the camera. To do that, I start a new `Activity` with the following code :

`intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(myFile));
startActivityForResult(intent,100);`

To be alerted when the picture is taken, I implemented the `onActivityResult` function. I was expecting this function to be launched after a picture is taken by the user (or after he cancels the action) but it is launched immediatly after the `StartActivityForResult` call, with the result code set to `RESULT_CANCELED`. From the user point of view, everything seems normal : the camera application is launched and it is possible to take a picture. When done, the application asks if the picture must be saved and, after the question is answered, my application is resumed.

Any idea why the `onActivityResult` function is launched immediately with a `RESULT_CANCELED` return code instead of being launched when the picture is taken and with the `RESULT_OK` return code?

To continue to investigate, I have created a new simple application with the code below :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id==R.id.Photo){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        View view;

        builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_box,null);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK",new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }               
        });         
        ((Button)vue.findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File file,directory;
                Intent intent;

                intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                directory= new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"Test");;

                if (!directory.exists()){
                    if (!directory.mkdirs()){
                        file= null;
                    }
                }

                file= new File(directory.getPath()+File.separator+"temp.jpg");

                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));

                startActivityForResult(intent,100);
            }
        });         
        constructeur.create().show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode==100){
        if (resultCode== RESULT_OK) {           
            Toast.makeText(this,"Image saved  "+data.getData().getPath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

The picture app is launched by a click on a button present in the dialog box. This time, the `onActivityResult` is correctly launched when the camera app is exited, but another problem arises : despite a "RESULT_OK" return code, no picture is saved and  the `data` field passed to the `onActivityResult` is null!(????)

The problem was certainly related to my file so I changed it. Now, the camera app returns "RESULT_OK", as expected,  when the picture is taken and saved, but the `onActivityResult` stll receives a null data. The picture is correctly saved in the specified file.

In the log file, I get two errors :

"Activity com.example.testphoto.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindows$DecorView that was originally added here"

and

"java.lang.RuntimeException : Unable to resume activity {com.example.testphoto/com.example.testphoto.MainActivity} : java.lang.RuntimeException : Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,request=100, result=-1,data=null} to activity {com.example.testphoto/com.example.testphoto.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Any idea about what causes these two errors?

Comment: Does `myFile` exist? Are you testing this with a real device?

Comment: `myFile`does not exist since I want it to be created by the camera app. And yes, I'm using a real device.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().
        getAbsolutePath()+ "/myfolder");
tempFolder.mkdir();

File myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
        + "/myfolder", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10646519/3249477)

Comment: I already have similar lines. The difference is that my `File` is located in the external storage public directory dedicated to pictures. I can add that, if I confirm that I want my picture to be stored, it is properly recorded at the location specified in the intent's extra.

Comment: @VD63 have you set the external storage permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have already declared the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`permission.

Comment: I have modified my question to incorporate more information about what I do.